# How can I prevent jquery.hover() from flickering other elements when moving the mouse between elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-hover

**The CODE**

```
function wkHover(){
$('.worksItem').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({ top: '-10px' }, 300, 'swing', {queue: false});
        $('.worksItem').not(this).animate({ opacity: '0.5' }, 300, 'swing', {queue: false});            
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({ top: '0' }, 200, 'swing', {queue: false});
        $('.worksItem').animate({ opacity: '1' }, 200, 'swing', {queue: false});
    });
}
```

http://egegorgulu.com/works

http://jsfiddle.net/vJQEQ/17/

All right so I have two problems:

1. When hovering between items, it naturally triggers the mouseout function when going over the margins, which creates this unpleasant flashy effect. What I want to do is just animate the ones being hovered out of and hovered in to so that the rest will stay the same. Any ideas?
2. Try moving the mouse quickly around all of the elements, and try not to go into an epileptic seizure. Anyway to prevent this?

Comment: For 2: use jquery `dequeue` function. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972754/how-to-run-jquery-code-in-the-javascript-onclick-function/8972839#8972839) question with similar problem

Comment: I'm not sure about where to call these. Can you guys elaborate a bit?

Comment: @nacho yes but unsuccessfully :/

Comment: @gdoron I did some digging and dequeueing seems to be the way here. Can you elaborate this please?

Comment: Give me a working JSFiddle, And I will try editing it, I can't edit your website...

Comment: @gdoron http://jsfiddle.net/QkRYz/ I was trying in this one...

Comment: @gdoron here you go http://jsfiddle.net/vJQEQ/17/

Comment: I have been working on it a while, I found the solution. Making a working fiddle now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssEZm/). The key is to [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the animation before adding a new one to the queue:

```
$(this).stop(true, true).animate(/***/);
```

However; this causes problems because multiple animations have to be run at once, so calling `.stop()` would interfere with the wrong animation. Therefore the different animations will have to be put in different animation [`queues`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```
$(this).stop('jump', true, true).animate({/***/}, {
  queue: 'jump'
});
```

If you use a different queue from the default (`fx`), you have to [`.dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) them manually.

```
$(this).stop('jump', true, true).animate({/***/}, {
  queue: 'jump'
})
.dequeue('jump');
```

[Edit] As for the first problem, I think the best solution is to [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) the fade-out animation, to give the cursor some time to move on to the next block. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Pu2/) with that included:

```
$(this).stop('fade', true).delay(300, 'fade').animate({ //***
```

This has some downsides, mainly due to the fact that [`.stop()` does not cancel timeouts that were set by `.delay()`](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/stop-does-not-clear-delay). My best solution is to have you choose between the "flash-effect" from the first fiddle, or the delayed fade-in effect from the second fiddle.

Comment: Now the only problem left, is that when you hold your cursor in the bottom 10px of a box, it will jump up and down like a little girl. This can be fixed by introducing an invisible hit-area div overlay, but I'm not going to do that for you :)

Comment: That's different across browsers though.

Comment: thanks, man. works like a charm. Didn't have the little girl problem in chrome as well.  What do you think about the first problem? I've been fiddling around and couldn't find a solution about it. Maybe something with timeouts? I dunno :/

Comment: Oh, I couldn't reproduce the first problem using my fiddle?

Comment: Ahh, I reinterpreted your problem description and I think I get it now, you only want the blocks to fade back to 1 alpha once your cursor leaves the blocks _and_ the spaces between the blocks?

Comment: you, sir, should get a medal. the second is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `stop` method passing 2 arguments `stop(false, true)` where first argument is to clear the queue or not and second jump to the end of the current animation. Try this.

```
$('.worksItem').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(false, true)
    .animate({ top: '-10px' }, 300, 'swing', {queue: false});
    $('.worksItem').not(this).stop(false, true)
    .animate({ opacity: '0.5' }, 300, 'swing', {queue: false});            
}, function(){
    $(this).stop(false, true)
    .animate({ top: '0' }, 200, 'swing', {queue: false});
    $('.worksItem').not(this).stop(false, true)
    .animate({ opacity: '1' }, 200, 'swing', {queue: false});
});
```